# change in custom directive ngClick event/function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a custom directive that i need to insert some login, basically i need in my custom directive prevent from being fired a function in ngClick, than depending in some logic that is made i will be calling a modal or the function/event that was in first place in the ngClick.
I been searching online for something similiar but i cant find it, maybe my terms search arent right.

How can i get the value from ngclick to store it and later fire it again?

directive:

```
 link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.on( 'click', function( evt ){
                evt.preventDefault()
                evt.stopImmediatePropagation();


                        $(element).on('click', function(e) {
                            return $scope[controllerName][clickTarget];
                        });

                        if(somelogic) {
                            evt.preventDefault()
                            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();



                                $uibModal.open({
                                    animation: true,
                                    backdrop: 'static',
                                    keyboard: false,
                                    templateUrl: 'template/path',
                                    size: 'lg',
                                    controller: 'SomeController',
                                    controllerAs: 'someCtrl',


                                });

                        }else{

                        //get the event/function from ngClick to be fire up
                        }
            });
        }
```

html:

```
<a ng-click="ctrl.modal();">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vut6kqsr/9/)** is sample. In this directive i am opening dialogbox iif checkbox is checked.

Your HTML will look like where "click-me" is my custom directve

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" click-me is-checked="isChecked">Show a Modal</a>
```

And directive will be

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           element.on('click', function(e) {
                if(scope.isChecked)
              {
                console.log('if');
                $uibModal.open({
                        animation: true,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                    controller: "ModalController"
                });
              }
              else
              {
                console.log('else ');
                scope.clickMe();
              }
           });
```

Comment: why dont you used mine as a example

Comment: I dont have your HTML and controller code but never mind i have updated  my sample and added modal dialog inside directive.

Comment: but this still doesnt resolve my issue, i need to get the function event of the ngClick to later forward to this place, basically my logic is based in case that the logic is false i have to go the the place that the ngClick functions had inside

Comment: if you are going to create new directive with element.on('click') will register one more function for element click. Also you already have ng-click on the same element which already registered click event on the same. So it will fire two functions and its bit difficult to avoid. So i would suggest create directive with click event and remove your ng-click and follow same as suggested above will resolve your issue. I have updated  my sample.